# Flutter Xcode: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: xcode, dart, flutter

I am getting this error while trying to build in Xcode. I tried deleting derived data and restarting Xcode but nothing helped.

```
ld: framework not found Flutter
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is the entire error log:

```
Ld /Users/chaythanyanair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-efsxwbzqcezyswaezzytcnxazinn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Runner normal x86_64
    cd /Users/chaythanyanair/Documents/Qburst/Learn/flutter_poc/ios
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.0.sdk -L/Users/chaythanyanair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-efsxwbzqcezyswaezzytcnxazinn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/chaythanyanair/Documents/Qburst/Learn/flutter_poc/ios/Pods/EstimoteSDK -L/Users/chaythanyanair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-efsxwbzqcezyswaezzytcnxazinn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alamofire -L/Users/chaythanyanair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-efsxwbzqcezyswaezzytcnxazinn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftKeychainWrapper -L/Users/chaythanyanair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-efsxwbzqcezyswaezzytcnxazinn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/device_info -L/Users/chaythanyanair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-efsxwbzqcezyswaezzytcnxazinn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/flutter_secure_storage -L/Users/chaythanyanair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-efsxwbzqcezyswaezzytcnxazinn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared_preferences -L/Users/chaythanyanair/Documents/Qburst/Learn/flutter_poc/ios/Flutter -F/Users/chaythanyanair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-efsxwbzqcezyswaezzytcnxazinn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/chaythanyanair/Documents/Qburst/Learn/flutter_poc/ios/Pods/EstimoteSDK/EstimoteSDK -F/Users/chaythanyanair/Documents/Qburst/Learn/flutter_poc/ios/Pods/../../../../flutter/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios -F/Users/chaythanyanair/Documents/Qburst/Learn/flutter_poc/ios/Flutter -filelist /Users/chaythanyanair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-efsxwbzqcezyswaezzytcnxazinn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/chaythanyanair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-efsxwbzqcezyswaezzytcnxazinn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/chaythanyanair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-efsxwbzqcezyswaezzytcnxazinn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner.swiftmodule -ObjC -lAlamofire -lSwiftKeychainWrapper -ldevice_info -lflutter_secure_storage -lshared_preferences -framework CoreBluetooth -framework CoreLocation -framework EstimoteSDK -framework Flutter -framework Foundation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -ObjC -lAlamofire -lSwiftKeychainWrapper -ldevice_info -lflutter_secure_storage -lshared_preferences -framework CoreBluetooth -framework CoreLocation -framework EstimoteSDK -framework Flutter -framework Foundation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/chaythanyanair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-efsxwbzqcezyswaezzytcnxazinn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Runner.app.xcent -lPods-Runner -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/chaythanyanair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-efsxwbzqcezyswaezzytcnxazinn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/chaythanyanair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-efsxwbzqcezyswaezzytcnxazinn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Runner
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I change to master channel.

```
flutter channel master
```

then run

```
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: Then fun   flutter upgrade

Comment: Even though it might have worked in 2020 or before. This didn't solve my issue in 2024.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for me:

- Delete the ios folder completely
- In the terminal, type `flutter create .`

And then try `flutter run` or press Play in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

For people coming here in 2020, I experienced this issue, ran the commands in the answer above (`flutter channel master`, `flutter upgrade`), and was then required to manually migrate my Xcode project to still work with the new version of Flutter. Info on that available here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-project-migration. Hope that can be of some help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
flutter upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

For me,

Deleted `Podfile.lock` and `pubspec.lock` first and then get pub & build worked.

If this doesn't work.

`flutter channel master` and then `flutter run`.